# Virtual attributes Rails - Unknown Attribute Error

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, virtual-attribute

I'm making a Rails 4 application. Each `incident` belongs to a `user`. Each incident `has many events`. I want that I can create an Incident with `current_user.incidents.new` and pass it an attribute `message` which exists in the Event model. On creation, I wish to create a new event with the said `message`.

Here's my Incident model.

```
class Incident < ActiveRecord::Base
  # The 'incident' model.
  # Incidents are created by Users (belongs_to :user)
  # Incidents may be public or private.
  # Incidents have many events (identified, fixing, etc.)

  belongs_to :user
  has_many :events
  validates :name, presence: true, length: {maximum: 256}
  validates_presence_of :component
  validates_presence_of :public
  validates_presence_of :user_id

  attr_accessor :message
  validates_associated :message, presence: true

  def message
    Event.find_by_incident_id(self.id).message
  end

  def message=(value)
    self.events.new(message: value, status: self.status)
  end

  private
    def incident_params
      params.require(:incident).permit(:name, :status, :user_id, :message)
    end

end
```

But, when I run `@i = Incident.new(message: 'something')`, I get `ActiveRecord::UnknownAttributeError: unknown attribute 'message' for Incident.`

Please help me figure this out.

Comment: You will need [`accepts_nested_attributes_for`](http://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/NestedAttributes/ClassMethods/accepts_nested_attributes_for) so that the Incident knows what to do with this attribute. then your `params` should be `.permit(:name,:status,:user_id,event_attributes: [ :message ])` This will also require changes to your form to use `fields_for` that references a new event. [This Tutorial](https://gorails.com/episodes/forum-nested-attributes-and-fields-for) might help better than my explanation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that you're passing the values to the default `ActiveRecord::new` method for `Incident`, which won't care about your getters, setters and accessors, it [goes straight to the columns](http://apidock.com/rails/v4.2.1/ActiveRecord/AttributeMethods/Serialization/ClassMethods/serialized_attributes).

Some people override or adapt the [build method](http://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/Relation/build) that can implement clever logic like you require, without affecting the base `initialize` method.

Answer (score 1):

Because your `Incident` model inherits from ActiveRecord::Base, it inherits the constructor.  The ActiveRecord constructor only accepts model attributes (db columns) as params.  You are trying to call an arbitrary instance method.  You could create a class method that creates an instance then adds the message:

```
def self.create_with_message(msg)
   i = Incident.new
   i.message(msg)
   return(i)
end
```

Comment: Thanks. But I'm more comfortable with Matt's answer. Seems more clean. But even this works.